# How to get email notifications from ONLY 1 Facebook group

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-groups

I have a Facebook account, but I don't really want to use Facebook. I only use Facebook for one group that only sends notifications through Facebook.

How would one get email notifications *only* from that one Facebook group? I also don't want to deal with people who send me friend requests (I deny them all).

Answer (score 1):

In Facebook, click the gear icon in the upper right to get to the settings menu, then choose "Privacy settings".

On the *Privacy Settings and Tools* page, click the link for "Notifications" in the left side menu.

You can now turn off all the notifications you want and leave just the one group.

Note that no matter what you do, there may be some notifications that you can't turn off.

See also: [Facebook Help: Notifications](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/327994277286267?rdrhc)